# Prove that ${p-1}\choose{k}$ $\equiv (-1)^k$ mod $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was solving a few problem in number theory in the book "elementary number theory" by David M. Burton, and i come across this question and yet i do not see how to think about it at all

Prove that if $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ is an integer satisfying $1 \leq k \leq p-1$, then the binomial coefficient

${p-1}\choose{k}$ $\equiv (-1)^k$ mod $p$.

Comment: As a side note, this is also true (but trivial) when $p=2.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do it by induction. Note that
$$\binom{p}{k} = \binom{p-1}{k} + \binom{p-1}{k-1}$$ 
is divisible by $p$. Therefore, 
$$\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv -\binom{p-1}{k-1} \mod p$$
so for induction step, assuming that
$$\binom{p-1}{k-1} \equiv (-1)^{k-1} \mod p$$
you easily deduce
$$\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^{k} \mod p.$$
The base case is trivial to check.

Comment: in the third step i don't understand how you get this assumption

Comment: @user146269 This is [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). To prove a property $P$ holds for all $k$, say $\binom{p-1}{k} \equiv (-1)^k \mod p$ for all $k$, you prove that it holds for $k = 0$ [base case] and then prove that if it holds for $k - 1$ then it holds for $k$ [induction].

Answer (score 1):

Note that $k!\equiv(-1)^k((p-1)(p-2)(\dots )(p-k)$ and then look at the factorial definition of the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, had to look uo ellipses in latex.

Comment: Where is Wilson's theorem used in this?

Comment: Oh, you're right that it isn't needed, since the $(p-1)! $ cancels from top and bottom. Thanks, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\dbinom{p-1}{k+1}=\dfrac{p-k-1}{k+1}\dbinom{p-1}{k}$.

For example, $\dbinom{12}{4}=\dfrac94\dbinom{12}{3}$

We note that $(p-k-1)+(k+1)=p$.

Then $p-k-1\equiv (-1)(k+1)\mod p$,

so $\dfrac{p-k-1}{k+1}\equiv -1\mod p$

and proceed by induction from $k=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(-1)^k=\displaystyle{-1\choose k},~$ and $~p-1\equiv-1\bmod p.$

Answer (score 0):

$$k!(p-1-k)!\equiv k\cdot (k-1)\cdots 1\cdot (p-1-k)!$$

$$\equiv (-1)^k(p-k)(p-(k-1))\cdots (p-1)\cdot (p-1-k)!$$

$$\equiv (-1)^k(p-1)!\pmod{p}$$